# Black Screen When Using on_enter Calling a Function with Kivy/Python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Python, and especially new to Kivy.
I'm sure that whatever I'm doing is a simple fix, but I just cannot figure it out for the life of me.

I've been doing this all in a Python file, with no my.kv.

What I'm trying to do is call a function upon entering the first screen of my app, but when I do this it just gives me a blank screen.

Sorry if my code is an absolute mess.

This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import requests 
import json

Builder.load_string("""
<Manager>:
    BuildScreen:
    SubmitScreen:
<BuildScreen>:
    name: 'page1'
    on_enter: app.BuildAnswer()


<SubmitScreen>:
    name: 'page2'
    on enter: app.SubmitAnswer()
    GridLayout:
        cols:1 
        row_force_default:True 
        row_default_height:40
        
        Button:
            text:"Return" 
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'page1'

""")


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class BuildScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SubmitScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TheLabApp(App):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(TheLabApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def BuildAnswer(self):   
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=40)
        self.spell = TextInput(hint_text = "Enter Spell", multiline=False)
        button = Button(text="Get Spell", on_release=self.SubmitAnswer)
        layout.add_widget(self.spell)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        return layout

    def SubmitAnswer(self):
        user_input = self.spell.text
        #making input into url ready thingy

        making_string = ''.join(str(x) for x in user_input)

        x = '-'.join(making_string.split())
        url = requests.get('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/' + x)

        #making it look pretty
        pretty_spells = json.dumps(url.json(), indent=2)

        #making it so I can get values from json 
        resp = json.loads(pretty_spells)

        print(resp['name'])
        print(resp['range'])
#the rest is just printing more of the spell's information

    def build(self):
        sm=ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(BuildScreen(name="page1"))
        sm.add_widget(SubmitScreen(name="page2"))
        return sm
```

Any and all help would be incredibly appreciated, as I've been trying to find a solution for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple problems with your code.

First, the `BuildAnswer()` method creates and returns a `layout`, but returning something from an `on_enter` method has no effect. If you want that `layout` to appear in the `BuildScreen`, you must explicitly add that `layout` to the `BuildScreen` instance.

Second, defining the `BuildAnswer()` method in the `TheLabApp` class makes it difficult to access the `BuildScreen` instance. This is because the `on_enter` method is triggered very early in the process (before the `root` of the `App` is assigned).

I suggest moving the `BuildAnswer()` method to the `BuildScreen` class, and calling `add_widget()` to actually add the created `layout` to the `BuildScreen` instance. To do that, start by modifying your `kv`:

```
<BuildScreen>:
    name: 'page1'
    on_enter: self.BuildAnswer()  # reflects new location of BuildAnswer()
```

And modifying your python code:

```
class BuildScreen(Screen):
    def BuildAnswer(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=40)
        self.spell = TextInput(hint_text="Enter Spell", multiline=False)
        button = Button(text="Get Spell", on_release=App.get_running_app().SubmitAnswer)  # to access the SubmitAnswer method
        layout.add_widget(self.spell)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        self.add_widget(layout)  # add layout to the GUI
        # return layout
```

And remove the `BuildAnswer()` method from the `TheLabApp` class.